# How to add a column to the Trash page?

Tags: functions, wp-admin, admin, columns, trash

I'm trying to add a column to the trash page for posts and pages but can't find a way to hook into that specific area. I've been able to use functions like [`manage_posts_columns`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_posts_columns) and [`manage_pages_columns`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_pages_columns) to add columns, but these hooks add columns to more than just the trash view.

I can see from the URL that the trash has `post_status=trash` but haven't found a way to hook into that. The generic `manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns` doesn't seem to fit since I need a post_status, not a post_type.

I've also looked at [`get_current_screen`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) but it doesn't return a post_status. Am I missing a function or obvious way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the value of the `post_status` query variable and make sure that it's set to `trash`:

```
function wpse239286_trash_column( $columns ) {

    // Bail if we're not looking at trash.
    $status = get_query_var( 'post_status' );
    if ( 'trash' !== $status ) {
        return $columns;
    }

    return array_merge( $columns, 
        array( 'trash_column' => __( 'Trash Column', 'text-domain' ) )
    );
}
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns' , 'wpse239286_trash_column' );
add_filter( 'manage_pages_columns' , 'wpse239286_trash_column' );
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. Having to use `$_GET['post_status']` feels kind of kludgy, but it looks like there's no hook available otherwise.

Comment: I'm with you on that. I dressed it up slightly, using `get_query_var( 'post_status' )` instead of checking `$_GET['post_status']` directly, but I didn't see a hook either.